# How do I delete a file named "-p" from bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, file-management, shell-script

How do I delete a file named `-p` in bash? Trying `rm "-p"` complains that -p is not a valid argument.

Comment: You write "delete a file" yet the title says "delete a folder". Please make the question consistent so that it gets properly indexed.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Most GNU tools support `--` to terminate the options.

```
rm -- -p
rm ./-p
```

Comment: Not just GNU tools, but all POSIX-compliant tools, and in practice all non-antique unix tools.

Answer (score 2):

The `NOTE` section in the man page for `rm` has something to say exactly about this. Apart from what [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://superuser.com/questions/148688/how-do-i-delete-a-folder-named-p-from-bash/148692#148692) has mentioned in their answer, one other way of removing such files, as mentioned in the man page, is by using an absolute path reference, such as: `rm /home/user/-p`.