# Unix tools: what if a file is named minus something?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, command-line-arguments, gnu

I'm always wondering: most GNU/Unix tools take options in the form "minus something", sometimes followed by an argument. What if you got a file named minus something?

```
$ ls
-f
$ rm -f
$ ls
-f
$ mv -f abc
mv: missing destination file operand after `abc'
Try `mv --help' for more information.
$ cat -f
cat: invalid option -- 'f'
Try `cat --help' for more information.
```

or

```
$ ls
-ohello.c
$ gcc -ohello -ohello.c
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

This is just out of curiosity; I don't have a use case for this.

Comment: You have to find a way of passing literally the string "-f" to the system call. Normally that's by careful escaping.

Comment: To the 'close because off-topic' voter: This is a question about shell **programming** and how to avoid a problem.  It is totally on-topic for SO.  (OTOH, it is probably a duplicate; the problem is finding the relevant other question.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I delete a file named "-p" from bash?](http://superuser.com/questions/148688/how-do-i-delete-a-file-named-p-from-bash)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To remove a file named `-x`, use `rm -- -x` (`--` means end of options) or `rm ./-x`.

Answer (score 10):

It is fairly common to ask this type of question in interview settings.  A common way to handle files with dashes is either:

```
$ rm -- -f
$ rm ./-f
```

Answer (score 7):

A common question in Unix. The main way is to give the full path name to the file, so it doesn't have a dash in front of it:

```
$ rm -file.txt
unknown option -l

$ rm ./-file.txt    #No problem!
$ rm $PWD/-file.txt #Same thing
```

**Some** commands, you can use a dash by itself (or a double dash) to end the options. However, this is not necessarily true with all commands, or even the same command on different systems.

```
$ rm -- -file.txt   #Works on Linux but not on some Unix systems
```

Answer (score 4):

you have to use

```
  rm -- <filename>
```

Ex:

```
  rm -- -f
```

Comment: Some remark wouldn't be wrong.