# How to escape "-" in bash

Tags: bash, escape-characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unix tools: what if a file is named minus something?](https://superuser.com/questions/419964/unix-tools-what-if-a-file-is-named-minus-something)

Please tell me how to escape this:

```
[root@unix ~]# ./-sh
-bash: ./-sh: Permission denied
[root@unix ~]# chmod +x -sh
chmod: invalid mode: `-sh'
Try `chmod --help' for more information.
[root@unix ~]#
```

Comment: # chmod a+x "\\-sh"
chmod: cannot access `\\-sh': No such file or directory

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use `--`.

E.g. `chmod +x -- -sh`. In GNU language the `--` means end of options, so `-sh` is no longer parsed as an option.

[Edit] Added example:

```
beetle:/home/hennes/test>touch -- -sh

beetle:/home/hennes/test>ls -l -- -sh
-rw------- 1 hennes users 0 2013-01-04 17:20 -sh

beetle:/home/hennes/test>chmod +x -- -sh

beetle:/home/hennes/test>ls -l -- -sh
-rwx------ 1 hennes users 0 2013-01-04 17:20 -sh
```

Comment: Interestingly, this doesn't seem to work with GNU echo, although it works with GNU printf. This works: `printf -- -sh`. And this does not: `echo -n -- -sh`.